# How to create HTML table for the JSON data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to extract only specific data from a "JSON" array.
so far i have tried doing this,please help me out.

```
<?php
$uri=$_POST['uri'];
$api_key=$_POST['api_key'];
$board=$uri.$api_key;
$value=file_get_contents($board);
$json_o=(array)json_decode($value);
//echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_o);//here is the result of request 
//echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

to fetch "uri"-It references the ".js" page

```
$("#btn2").click(function(event){
$.post( 
             "main.php",{api_key:"024b427a5d41a62",uri:"https://kanbanflow.com//v1/tasks?apiToken="},
             function(data) {
             $('#content').html(data);
             }
          );
});
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON structure?

Comment: its a big one mentor. Still do u want me to send?

Comment: Not the whole. Just want the outer structure

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal below is the JSON structure.'{"columnId":"258f2200948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7",
"columnName":"To-do",
"tasksLimited":false,
"tasks": 
[
{
"_id":"5f4d17eeff71cf48f8cf033db78c5755",
"name":"test",
"description":"",
"color":"yellow",
"columnId":"258f2200948711e3b4507b78fb18a9a7",
"totalSecondsSpent":0,
"totalSecondsEstimate":0
}
]}'

Comment: which properties you want to include from above json to table?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal name and description properties.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `data` using `each()` and construct the html

```
function(data){
 var myTable=$('#myTable');
  $(data).each(function(index,obj){
   // prepare TR & TDs for each row and append to myTable     
  })    
}
```